# Wow Carousel (Divi people) multiple slide issue

Tags: carousel, testimonials

Note: I have deleted the Divi cache and browser cache.

I am currently building a new website on WordPress with Divi builder.

I have attached 2 images. The first image shows 3 slides (desktop). You can see the navigation arrows left and right.

The second shows 4 slides. As soon as I change the number of slides from 3 to 4 the navigation arrows disappear on both sides.

[3 slides](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tXYjk.png)

[4 slides](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K0BgE.png)

I have deleted the Divi cache and browser cache which made no difference

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.